# Pass mobx store and props to function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I have a React component which calls a function, and i need to pass the injected mobx store and the components props into this function

```
const Component = inject("store")(observer(({store, props}) => {
   return (
       <div>
          {_someRenderFunction(store, props)}
      </div>
   );
}));
```

It's used in the function like this

```
function _someRenderFunction(store, props) {
   let data = store.data;
   const { cookies } = props;
   ...
}
```

But i get the error `Cannot read property 'cookies' of undefined`

How can i pass both the store and component props to the `_someRenderFunction`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
({store, props}) => {};
```

Your component receives only props so the basic definition would be:

```
(props) => {}
```

Inject gives you your injected store inside the given props. So what you receive is:

```
const props = { store: STORE_INSTANCE }
```

With the object destructing you can extract properties from props. So this would also work:

```
({ store }) => {}
```

Here you are extracting the property store from your props. but in your example you are also extracting the property props from props. So in your case props should look like:

```
const props = { store: STORE_INSTANCE, props: PROPS_OBJECT }
```

This is not what you want. So object destructing is not what you want in this case. The following code should work:

```
const Component = inject("store")(observer((props) => {
   return (
       <div>
          {_someRenderFunction(props)}
      </div>
   );
}));

function _someRenderFunction(props) {
   const { cookies, store } = props;
   let data = store.data;
   ...
}
```